# Check user claims during request in ASP .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, claims-based-identity

I have defined policies in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyTypes.Engines.Get, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim(CustomClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.Engines.Get);
    });
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyTypes.Engines.Manage, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim(CustomClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.Engines.Manage);
    });
});
```

Permissions class:

```
public static class Permissions
    {
        public static class Engines
        {
            public const string Manage = "engines.manage";
            public const string Get = "engines.get";
        }
}
```

Later I implemented endpoint in controller with defined policy.

```
[Authorize(Policy = PolicyTypes.Engines.Get)]
[HttpGet(Name = "Engines")]
public IEnumerable<Engine> GetAll()
{
    IEnumerable<Engine> engines = repository.GetAll<Engine>();
    return engines;
}
```

I test via postman using Bearer token to check access to this endpoint. Tested user had policy `PolicyTypes.Engines.Manage`. Result of decoded token.

```
{
  "sub": "test@test.com",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "claims": [
    {
      "Issuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
      "OriginalIssuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
      "Properties": {},
      "Subject": null,
      "Type": "projectname/permission",
      "Value": "engines.manage",
      "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    },
    {
      "Issuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
      "OriginalIssuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
      "Properties": {},
      "Subject": null,
      "Type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
      "Value": "Constructor",
      "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    }
  ],
  "iss": "dotnet_TEST",
  "aud": "TEST",
  "nbf": 1534023667,
  "iat": 1534023667,
  "exp": 1534027267
}
```

When I execute request I get code 200 and result json form endpoint. What can be the reason that I don't get 403 forbidden?

I present code to generate token.

```
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetValidClaims(User user)
        {
            IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();
            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await options.JtiGenerator()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(options.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
            new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
        };
            var userClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            claims.AddRange(userClaims);
            //foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            //{
            //    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            //    var role = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
            //    if (role != null)
            //    {
            //        var roleClaims = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            //        foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
            //        {
            //            claims.Add(roleClaim);
            //        }
            //    }
            //}
            return claims;
        }

        public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(User user)
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = await this.GetValidClaims(user);

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: options.Issuer,
                audience: options.Audience,
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: options.NotBefore,
                expires: options.Expiration,
                signingCredentials: options.SigningCredentials);

            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            return encodedJwt;
        }
```

Comment: Is that a JSON Web Token?

Comment: @poke Yes I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON Web Tokens, claims are encoded directly as part of the JWT payload. The additional information that the [`Claim` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim?view=netstandard-2.0) has are not encoded in JWT.

All that JWT cares about is the claim type, and the claim value. And those are encoded as direct properties of the JWT payload.

So your claims should be encoded like this:

```
{
  "sub": "test@test.com",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "projectname/permission": "engines.manage",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Constructor",
  "iss": "dotnet_TEST",
  "aud": "TEST",
  "nbf": 1534023667,
  "iat": 1534023667,
  "exp": 1534027267
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example how to generate token in that way?

Comment: When you create a [`JwtSecurityToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytoken.aspx) with a claims list, then you should automatically get a correct token when you write it using [`JwtSecurityTokenHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.aspx). If you are having problems, show the code you are currently using to generate the token.